# How to draw chart for heart rateing?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, charts

I am developing an application that is heart rate app.

I would like to dislay heart rate in Chart view.

Could you tell me how to implement it or there is any chart framework for this case?

Please give me advise!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using CorePlot framework is little bit complicated, but its good.

Otherwise if you need very simple Graph then go for [ECGraph](https://code.google.com/p/ecgraph/)

Answer (score 2):

Use CorePlot for that, I've used it in the past and it was great:

[CorePlot](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/)